# SQL Server : input a string of IDs and Return a string of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `tblEventDates` with `DateID` and `EventDate` columns. I need to provide a stored procedure the param of `@DateIDs` which is a string of `DateID`s separated by a pipe, and return a string of `EventDates` separated by a comma.

This is what I have tried so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParseDates]
    @DateIDs VARCHAR(100),
    @ReturnDates VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT,
            @DateID INT,
            @D VARCHAR(8000),
            @TmpDate VARCHAR(8000)          

    SET @D = @DateIDs
    SET @i = CHARINDEX('|', @D)

    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @DateID = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@D, 1, @i - 1))

        SELECT @TmpDate = EventDate  
        FROM tblEventDates 
        WHERE DateID = @DateID

        SET @ReturnDates = CONCAT(@ReturnDates, ', ', @TmpDate)

        SET @D = SUBSTRING(@D, @i + 1, 9999)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX('|', @D)

        CONTINUE
    END

    IF LEN(@D) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TmpDate = EventDate  
        FROM tblEventDates 
        WHERE DateID = @DateID

        SET @ReturnDates = CONCAT(@ReturnDates, ', ', @TmpDate)
    END
END
GO
```

So if `@DateIDs = '65|67|69'`,  `@ReturnDates` should be `'01/15/2019, 01/16/2019, 01/17/2019'`.

Comment: Just a side note.  Loops should be avoided as often as possible.  If not 2016+, there are far more performant parse/split functions available.

Comment: John, thanks for the input. Sql is not my area of expertise, so point well taken and appreciated

Comment: In SQL, it's best of you don't mess around with delimited strings at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a brute force option as well

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '65|67|69'

Set @S='|'+@S+'|'
Select @S = replace(@S,concat('|',DateID,'|'),'|'+convert(varchar(10),EventDate,101)+'|')
 From  tblEventDates

Select replace(substring(@S,2,len(@S)-2),'|',', ')
```

**Returns**

```
01/15/2019, 01/16/2019, 01/17/2019
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but when I run the query the result I get is: 03/04/04/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/08/20111/12/2015/07/20109/14/2014/04/03/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/10/2015, 03/04/04/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/08/20111/12/2015/07/20109/14/2014/04/05/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/10/2015, 03/04/04/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/08/20111/12/2015/07/20109/14/2014/09/10/2014/04/07/20109/11/20107/12/2015/01/04/07/20109/12/20107/10/2015

Comment: @SteveKrantzman Try the updated answer.  I forgot to keep the delimiters

Comment: @SteveKrantzman Just in case here is a dbFiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6ba344f80915f8b45b9aa1ec8e6d13a6

Answer (score 0):

Providing you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can leverage the `STRING_SPLIT` function to turn the delimited `@DateIDs` string into a table, join that against your date table (which I have called `my_date_table` with the fields `id` and `date_value`), and then concatenate the dates using a trick involving `JSON_VALUE` and `REPLACE` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672860/6389010)):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dates;

SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), my_date_table.date_field, 101) AS date_string
INTO #dates
FROM my_date_table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [value]
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DateIDs, '|')  
) date_ids
    ON date_ids.[value] = my_date_table.id
;

SET @returnDates = COALESCE(
    JSON_VALUE(
        REPLACE(
            (
                SELECT
                    _ = date_string
                FROM #dates
                FOR JSON PATH
            )
        ,'"},{"_":"',', '),'$[0]._'
    )
, '');
```

Comment: e_i_pi, Thank you for your answer. While your answer works equally as well, John's was easier for me to understand and was achieved with fewer lines of code (and who doesn't like fewer lines).  As I am not a SQL expert, I do not know if one is more efficient, or a best practice, so I had to base my choice on what I personally liked best.